# Yii2 : To exclude an attribute in afterFind() function

Tags: php, gridview, yii, yii2

I have created_at and updated_at column in DB and I am filling it with timestamp.

To show the created_at and updated_at date in index.php(To the user in GridView) I have converted the timestamp to YYYY-MM-DD format using afterFind function in Model.

From the GridView if an edit button is clicked, I need to update a status in the row. So my code in the controller is

```
$existingRow = Project::findOne($id) // From the parameter
$existingRow->status = 2
$existingRow->save()
```

On executing the above command, the created_at field is saving with "YYYY-MM-DD" format which is converted from "afterFind()" function in the model.

How can I get the non-converted timestamp value to be saved ?

Comment: Why dont you just do the convertion on your gridview. Its the best practice.

Comment: I could do that and it will be so much easy. But I want to find, is there any other way in the controller to do that. Some new code may help. :)

Answer (score 3):

To handle `created_at` and `updated_at` you should use a [`TimestampBehavior`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-timestampbehavior.html). In your corresponding model add:

```
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        TimestampBehavior::className(),
    ];
}
```

Then it will automatically fill your fields on create/update your model.

To display it properly in `GridView`, define your column like:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   'columns' => [
       'id',
       'name',
       'created_at:datetime',    // or 'created_at:date' for just date
       // ...
   ],
]) ?>
```

`afterFind()` is not best solution to such things.

Comment: Instead of this TimestampBehavior I have used beforeSave function to get the current timestamp. Is that a good practise ?.

Comment: Not really in this case, especially if you have really good out of box solution. It will take you additional 5 minutes to adjust your code to `TimestampBehavior`, but it's worth in long term.

Comment: Using this TimestampBehavior is working fine and thanks for the answer. Earlier we were using beforeSave and afterFind for the changes. afterFind() may be helpful when writing API's I guess

Answer (score 0):

Just like you overrode afterFind(), you can override the `beforeSave()` method in your model, to reformat the attributes to the required format before the Save operation is executed.

```
protected function beforeSave()
{
  $parentResult = parent::beforeSave();


  // pseudo code
  // Change any attributes values as you require
  // return true if successful ($result)

  return $parentResult && $result; // Save operation will run if this returns true only
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the expected answer, but this function got me what I want. Using **$model->getOldAttribute($attributeName)** gives the original data which is in the database (which is the original data not converted by afterFind() function).

```
 $existingRow = ProjectResourceAssign::findOne($id);
 $existingRow->status = 2;
 // This piece of line will get you the original value of the attribute
 $existingRow->created_at = $existingRow->getOldAttribute('created_at');
 $existingRow->save(false);
```

Comment: Is this an answer? (if so, please explain how it solves the problem; if not, perhaps it should be an edit to the question - use the "edit" button immediately under the question to add it)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. This is one of the solution for the question. I'll add details to the answer.